# How can I use LibGDX with AR library

Tags: android, libgdx, augmented-reality

I need to implement location based app with augmented reality. I draw a model with simple interaction with it (that's why I've chosen LibGDX) and I need to place this model on some point at the real world.

My small research gave me some solutions (like [this](https://glud.github.io/trascendentAR/) or [this](https://github.com/daemontus/VuforiaLibGDX)). But all of them use marker-based drawing, but I need to draw model on surface.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Person from Google has made some effort with ARCore using Libgdx, and had created a blog:
 [Investigating ARCore with LibGDX](https://medium.com/@wilkinsonclay/investigating-arcore-with-libgdx-f69b83764118)

Take a look at BaseARCoreActivity, which we can use to show some 3D Modle defined in Libgdx.